# Google Map location reset when admob InterstitialAd is closed.

Tags: android, google-maps, admob

My application contains Google Map and it display admob InterstitialAd.

I notice on android higher version, like 4.0, when admob InterstitialAd is displayed and user just close InterstitialAd. Google Map restart to it's initial location. Which imply that either "onCreate" on most likely "onResume" method get called.

However, I notice this problem dont happen with Android 2.3 which I was using for testing.

Is there away to fix this, or could I just save the current location that Google map is displaying so that I could show it again when "onResume" get called.

Comment: share your code so that it could be understood better. and you are correct that onResume will get called. you sure that you aren't touching the map in onResume? also check onPause if something is happening there

Comment: Yes, I'm touching the map at onResume. It could be the reason.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Post more information from your comment following would be the fixes:

1. Do not do any transformation on the map in the onResume method, because onResume is called when the control returns back to the app from the ad.
2. Set a flag to check if the onResume was called after displaying an ad and skip the operations on map in those cases.